# How do I set default includes for custom JSON:API Resources?

Tags: 9

The [JSON:API Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_extras) module includes the **JSON:API Extras Defaults** submodule, which enables you to set default includes for JSON:API.  For example, to include an entity reference to the tags vocabulary for articles, I can go to `/admin/config/services/jsonapi/resource_types/node--article` and add "tag" to the **Default include list** under **Collection**.

Now, I want to include some referenced entities by default for a custom resource that I made with the [JSON:API Resources](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonapi_resources) module.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `include` parameter of the query directly in the code for your custom resource:

```
  public function process(Request $request): ResourceResponse {
    // Set the default includes.
    $request->query->set('include',  'tags,mediaReference.file');
```

You can include multiple values separated by commas.  Note that the above code overwrites the `include` parameter; if you want to allow users to also add their own includes, you can check for `$request->query->has('include')` first.